# Does profile completeness affect visibility on Careers.SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On StackOverflow Careers you are asked to provide education details and then complete details inside of that to raise your completeness score.

[image: 1]]

Does this affect my visibility on careers.SO in any way? Such as priority in search results, or any other type of "score" relating to completeness?

As the [2016 Developer Survey shows](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-education) most of us don't have a formal education, so most of us are constantly being told we haven't completed our profile.

[image: 2]]

Maybe there could be some type of option that says you are self taught and eliminates the nag message, because it's basically saying "go to college and complete your profile" haha.

Comment: I think the majority of the algorithm relies on things like tags more than completeness.

Comment: You just have to ignore that.  This info is intended for SE customers, as a basic service to those customers they try to get you to disclose as much info as possible.  Just tell them what you consider relevant and what you want to disclose, avoid making anything up.

Comment: @HansPassant that makes sense. Ofc we avoid making things up on CVs haha, I call out everything and if the candidate can't explain why it's on there they get an F.

Comment: BTW 69% of respondents say they are self-taught in addition to learning how to code by other means. Your misinterpretation of that section is an extremely common one. I just want to set the record straight =)

Comment: @samthebrand I understood that it didn't mean *only* self taught as there is another comment right below it saying `13% of respondents across the globe tell us they are *only self-taught*`, but I was careless with how I presented it here :P

Comment: Oh gotcha @Josiah. I'm probably just seeing things that aren't there then. (I've seen too many people interpret that particular chart wrong, and it's my fault for making it so easy to misinterpret.)

Comment: @samthebrand well I do recall seeing copy along the lines of "With this many developers without a degree, if your company's hiring requirements include a BS you may want to update your strategy".. And that seemed like maybe you guys were just as confused as us about what that stat meant at first :P